# Allow users who are not administrators to respond using message command?

Tags: command-line

Is it possible to allow users on a Windows 10 server to respond using the message command prompt if they are not in the administrators group?

Lets say we want to send a message to all the users to notify that a program (eg MYOB) is closing at 1pm.

```
 msg * /v /w /time:120 Hi All, MYOB is closing at 1pm today
```

We can see that they have read the message by using the /w prompt. But what if one wants to request a 10 minute delay to finish a task? Unless they are in the administrators group, they cannot respond via msg. Is there any way of allowing this?

Because it is all part of a batch script that is then set to execute automatically at 1pm, it would be helpful to allow responses to the message if that is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've had no other answer, let me point out a couple of thoughts.

First, Unix has a nice "sudo" command that lets people elevate, but only to run a certain command.  The last time I checked, if I remember correctly, Microsoft Windows does not provide a similar capability.

Second, if you just want to send a message, you might be able to do it another way.  e.g., if you provide the computers with a "respond-message.bat" which opens Notepad, allows a user to type a message and save the file, then copies that file over SMB.  Or FTP.  Just because the outgoing message uses the msg command doesn't mean that the reply needs to come back the same way.

Comment: Notepad could work.